# Angular $http error function never called for 127.0.0.1

Tags: http, angularjs

I use Angular version:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

This is my controller:

```
function HelloController($scope,$http) {
    $scope.greeting = {
        text : 'Hello'
    };

    $scope.clickMe = function() {
        $http.get('127.0.0.1:10880', {params: {tsn:'10'}})
             .success(function(data,status,header,config) {
                 $scope.greeting.text ='This is cool';
             }).error(function(data,status,header,config) {
                 $scope.greeting.text ='We have error';
             });    

        $scope.greeting.text ='None';
    };
}
```

I have nothing running on port 10880. If I use 127.0.0.1 in $http.get function error has never called. But if I use localhost insted of 127.0.0.1 error function gets called. I am not shure is this Angular problem at all. I use Linux.

Thanks for any idea

Zlaja

Comment: Do you see a outgoing request on 127.0.0.1:10880 on the network tab of your debugger ?

Comment: No, there is no outgoing request

Answer (score 0):

If you add `http://` before `127.0.0.1:xxxx` it should work.

I don't have more explanation why. I'm trying to find something relevent from the source of $http service.